# Processing Library for Java in Netbeans - load an image without extending PApplet

Tags: java, netbeans, processing

Working in Netbeans, having included the processing.core import, I was trying to do something like the following in a method...

```
 PApplet pbase = new PApplet();
 PImage img = pbase.loadImage(filePath);
 pbase.set(0,0,img);
 pbase.save(newFilePath);
```

.. instead of using the "MyClass extends PApplet" method since I'm not planning to draw anything on screen. I just wish to use the processing library image functions available within the applet.

Apart from the above code, the only additional thing I've done is include the import processing.core.

Am I obliged to create a class and use it in PApplet.main("my.package.mainmethod") or can I just use it like a standard library (i.e. the above)?

The above always gives me a nullpointer exception. I've read somewhere that the code I've written doesn't generate a canvas which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
PApplet pbase = new PApplet();
pbase.init();
PImage img = pbase.loadImage(filePath);
```

I forgot about the call to init() - the clue being in the Applet!